# select options reset to default value after refreshing the page

Tags: php, tags, html-select

I am using the **select option** to select the category from the dropdown list.
when I select the category and submit it..the page is refreshing and the category is reset to default value.
I need to display the selected category after refreshng the page also.
may anyone help me to do this one?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="frm" action="" method="post">
<select name="dp" >
<option>Select</option>
<option <?php if (isset($_POST['dp']) && ($_POST['dp']== 'Option 1')) echo " selected='selected'";?> value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
<option <?php if (isset($_POST['dp']) && ($_POST['dp']== 'Option 2')) echo " selected='selected'";?> value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option <?php if (isset($_POST['dp']) && ($_POST['dp']== 'Option 3')) echo " selected='selected'";?> value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @Manu..I have tried the above code but it is not successfull..The value is restting after reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

try to used `$_SESSION` to save the submitted value of option and try again Manu's script just change `$_POST`