# select previously selected dropdown value on form self submit

Tags: php, html

I have a 'this year' dropdown with a form attached. I then select one of the years, like say 2016. When I click the submit button I want the page to be reloaded while the value in the dropdown stays at 2016 (the one that was previously selected).

How can I do that? Here's my form:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" id="myID" name="myName">
   <label id="year" name="year">YEARS</label>
      <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control">
        <option value="0" selected disabled="">CHOOSE YEAR</option>
          <?php foreach($year as $rows){?>
          <option value="<?php echo $rows->years?>"><?php echo $rows->years?>
          </option>
          <?php }?>
      </select>
    <button id="filter_button" style="margin-top: 26px" name="filter_button" 
     type="submit" class="for btn btn-info">Show</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: You will merely need to pull the value from `$_POST['year']` and write a condition to make it the `selected` option.  Did you do any research before posting this question?  Also, you don't need to write the `value` attribute if it is the same as the option text.

Comment: Dynamically set the `selected` attribute of the option (which you're already doing for the `CHOOSE YEAR` option). This can be done either via form submission, and then retrieval from the database, or via JavaScript's `localStorage`.

Comment: did some reasearch but not what i want, because usually i never post form within its own page, so i kinda confuse how to achieve that

Comment: @mickmackusa well if u can link me with some duplicate its fine, cause i also still looking for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select options reset to default value after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802023/select-options-reset-to-default-value-after-refreshing-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the value from `$_POST` to set the selected as default. Below is the updated code:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" id="myID" name="myName">
   <label id="year" name="year">YEARS</label>
      <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control">
        <option value="0" selected disabled="">CHOOSE YEAR</option>
          <?php foreach($year as $rows){
             $isSelected = (isset($_POST['year']) && ($_POST['year'] == $rows->years)) ? 'selected' : '';
          ?>
          <option <?php echo $isSelected; ?> value="<?php echo $rows->years?>"><?php echo $rows->years?>
          </option>
          <?php }?>
      </select>
    <button id="filter_button" style="margin-top: 26px" name="filter_button" 
     type="submit" class="for btn btn-info">Show</button> 
</form>
```